# Clock and calendar application

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

i want to make Clock Calendar application but I'm confusing, i see a lot of packs in android: Time, Date, Calendar, Gregorian, Time SQL... Time is deprecated on my target api 16. This package is newer then Gregorian and I`m confused, what pack to use? Tank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a great exercise for you.  I would start with the Calendar class.  All the functionality that you will need is there and every device supports it.